# Quotients of 4-sphere by smooth $Z_p$ actions with knotted fixed point sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 4-manifolds

This question is closely related to [another I asked today](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249465/quotient-of-s3-by-montgomery-and-zippins-wild-involution).

Giffen [showed](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2373054.pdf) in 1966 that the generalized Smith conjecture is false by constructing for odd $p$ a smooth $Z_p$ action on $S^4$ with fixed-point set a knotted $S^2$.

> Is there a topological description of the quotient?

D. W. Sumners in 1975 extended Giffen's work by giving a [different construction](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1997199.pdf) which also worked for $p$ even. I would be equally happy with a description of this quotient. More generally, I would be satisfied with a topological description of the quotient of any four-sphere by any smooth cyclic action that fixes a knotted two-sphere.